# Как определить протокол: http или https?

Tags: java, url

У класса `URL` имеется такой конструктор:

```
URL(String protocol, String host, String file)
```

Как видно, в нём можно указать протокол по которому будет отправлен запрос к ресурсу. Например, есть ресурс с файлом https://site.com/example_file.doc.
Правильный конструктор будет иметь вид: `URL("https","site.com","example_file.doc")`
Как можно заранее узнать по какому протоколу обращаться к ресурсу, что бы создать верный конструктор?
Ведь я заранее не могу знать, работает ли ресурс через http или https.
Прошу подсказать, спасибо.

Comment: Открыть сайт браузером вы, конечно, уже пробовали?

Comment: Не понял вопроса, вон же прямо в ссылке написано https, не?

Comment: аргумент при запуске программы такой: `site.ru` Тот, кто задаёт аргумент - браузер открывать не умеет, то есть имя сайта подаётся в качестве аргумента при запуске программы.

Comment: Тогда пихайте http, если что сайт отредиректит на https

Comment: Без обращения к сайту протокол, естественно, определить нельзя: базы данных протоколов для всех сайтов нет, от имени протокол не зависит. Так что единственный способ это сначала пробовать один протокол и, если не получится, пробовать другой.

Comment: К сожалению, если  сайт работает с https, то при обращении к `http://site.ru/robots.txt` он не будет редиректить к `https://site.ru/robots.txt`.  Хотя, если это проделать в браузере - редирект будет. Вот, что странно.

Comment: А он должен редиректить? Смотрите содержимое ответа сервера. Он скорее всего поправит версию протокола и его имя в заголовке Response.